# Swift: Long Press Gesture Recognizer - Detect taps and Long Press

Tags: ios, swift, long-press

I want to wire an action such that if the gesture is a tap, it does animates an object in a particular way but if the press duration was more than .5 secs it does something else.

Right now, I just have the animation hooked up. I don't know how I can differentiate between a long press and a tap? 
How do I access the press duration to achieve the above?

```
 @IBAction func tapOrHold(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0, animations: {

                self.polyRotate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1/3 * CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0, animations: {
                self.polyRotate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2/3 * CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0, animations: {
                self.polyRotate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3/3 * CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
            })

            }, completion: { (Bool) in
                let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextView")
                self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
        })
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Define two `IBActions` and set one `Gesture Recognizer` to each of them. This way you can perform two different actions for each gesture.

**You can set each `Gesture Recognizer` to different IBActions in the interface builder.**

```
@IBAction func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("tapped")
    //Your animation code.
}

@IBAction func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("longpressed")
    //Different code
}
```

**Through code without interface builder**

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("tapped")
}

func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("longpressed")
}
```

**Swift 5**

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
    
@objc func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("tapped")
}

@objc func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("longpressed")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly as if I long press, both the tap and the long press fire...

Comment: did you bind different IBActions for each Gesture Recogniser like in the code above. It works for me

Comment: Thanks for adding the code version as well, was only finding interface builder answers and starting to get frustrated

Comment: I have a table, in cellForRowAtIndexPath method I have written the code u suggested. How can I send the rowId to the action function ? @rakeshbs

Comment: @blue_zinc this solves the problem: 

tapGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: longPressRecognizer)

Answer (score 29):

**For swift2**

```
let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
lpgr.delegate = self
self.featuredCouponColView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

**Action**

```
//MARK: - UILongPressGestureRecognizer Action -
    func handleLongPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            //When lognpress is start or running
        }
        else {
            //When lognpress is finish
        }
    }
```

**For Swift 4.2/ Swift 5**

```
let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
lpgr.delegate = self
self.colVw.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

//MARK: - UILongPressGestureRecognizer Action -
    @objc func handleLongPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            //When lognpress is start or running
        }
        else {
            //When lognpress is finish
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

**Through code without interface builder**

```
// Global variables declaration
var longPressed = false
var selectedRow = 0



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ContactListTableViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
        longPressGesture.allowableMovement = 15 // 15 points
        longPressGesture.delegate = self
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

// Long tap work goes here !!
if (longPressed == true) {

       if(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType == .Checkmark){
                tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .None
                self.selectedRow -= 1

                if(self.selectedRow == 0){
                    self.longPressed = false
                }

            } else {
                self.selectedRow += 1
                tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }

        } else if(self.selectedRow == 0) {
          // Single tape work goes here !!
        }
```

**But the only problem is the long press gesture runs two times. If you have found any solution do comment below !**

Comment: Check for recognizer state `if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)`

Comment: @Arvis Where would you put this `if` statement to prevent multiple executions of the long press gesture function?

Comment: @PlateReverb in selector action function

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 using interface builder**

for the normal tap you can simply create a `touch up inside` action from your button.

for the long press, create an outlet for your button, create the tap gesture recognizer and set it to the button then create the selector method to perform the long press tasks.

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addToListButtonLongPress(_:)))
    longPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    longPressRecognizer.allowableMovement = 10
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    myButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}

// Connected to myButton in interface builder.
@IBAction func myButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button tapped")
}

@objc func myButtonLongPressed(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("button long pressed")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**iOS tapGesture and longPressGesture**

In this example `onLongPress()` body will not be executed every time during changing or ending an motion

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClick))
self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onLongPress))
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)


@objc func onClick() {
    //logic
}

@objc func onLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.state == .began else { return }
    //logic
}
```